# If I have categories of Income, and I am running a logistic regression, do I make them dummy variables?

Tags: r, regression, classification, logistic-regression

So I have a logistic regression model to predict teenage pregnancy, where I have turned into dummy variables categories such as religion, race, father's highest degree, and so forth. I also turned into dummy variables the income groups such as low, medium, and high.

I was wondering if I was actually meant to turn the Income group into dummy variables since, for example, with religion every religion is pretty much separate but Income is still sort of numerical and ascending as low incomes have lower dollar amounts, and high incomes have higher dollar amounts. I'm not sure if I am explaining this correctly, but I was shocked to see that my stepwise regression with R has removed Income as a significant coefficient for predicting teenage pregnancy. I think what I am referring to is ordinal variables upon further research.

Comment: 1) If you have income as numeric, keep it numeric, don't bin the data, you will loose what you have mentioned, the nuances in it. 2) Even if you decide to bin a numeric variable, there is no need to create the dummies by hand, base R's modeling functions do it for you. Include income as a RHS variable and that's almost surely it.

Comment: Upon further research Income and Education seem to be ordinal data. Do I have to make them factors or is there something else I should do?

Comment: Income shouldn't be ordinal but you have to go with the data you have. It's difficult to impossible to say without seeing the data.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.